# JetBrains Rider EAP on Linux: how to start service

Tags: c#, linux, mono, jetbrains-ide, rider

During tests of the JetBrains Rider EAP under Linux Mint I ported one of my MSVC C# projects which was Windows service project. All was Ok with porting but how I can start the module as a service from IDE? I know that I have to use mono-service to start it but maybe it is possible to start and stop my service from Rider?

Comment: You have no way to start/stop a service in VS, so I don't expect you can do the that in Rider.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I completely forgot that  in Windows I started and stopped it via terminal. The question is closed

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, It was my fault. In Windows I started and stopped it using terminal. The question is closed.